# How to manage packages in Meteor.js?

Tags: meteor

I couldn't find a clear answer for this anywhere so here it is. Instead of constantly doing

`meteor add <package-name>`

whenever I want to install a new package. Or instead of creating a bash script that adds and removes all of the packages, it would be nice if there was a more elegant way of doing this. Kind of like `packages.json` files for `npm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `.meteor/packages` (all `meteor add <package-name>` does is adding a line in this file)
Additionally, Meteor now supports npm packages directly (since the 1.3 release) and I'd recommend using them for anything that is not particularly related to Meteor. For that you use traditional the npm flow, ie a `package.json` at the root and `npm install`

Then in your scripts, you'd do

`import {ReactMeteorData} from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';`

to import from the Meteor `react-meteor-data` package, and

`import React, {Component} from 'react';` to import from the npm `react` package.

Comment: Thanks, still new to Meteor, didn't know this!

Comment: Question: but then do the packages download every time meteor is run? Where are they saved on disk?

Comment: Meteor resolves its packages when it detects changes in `.meteor/packages`, and you have to handle the npm packages yourself, as you do with traditional node app.

Answer (score 1):

Having to write here, as it wont allow to comment, yet.

I am on Ubuntu and my packages are at

```
~/.meteor/packages/<distribution>/<version>/<target(web.browser || web.cordova)
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that